# Why does my song restart when I change from vertical to horizontal view?

Tags: android, android-layout, media-player, android-mediaplayer, android-lifecycle

The songs I have are all MediaPlayers,  and when I change from horizontal to vertical orientation, or vice versa, the song stops, and then begins playing from the start of the song. I suspect that when i change the layout to horizontal or to vertical that the onPause() method is called or something. What can I do to prevent the song from restarting, and to just keep playing normally when I change from vertical to horizontal and vice versa? Would this have anything to do with the fact that I implemented these methods?

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    music.get(SongPlaying).stop();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    music.get(SongPlaying)).stop();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    music.get(SongPlaying)).stop();

}
```

Comment: Well, there would be *a really easy way to find out* .. -1 because this question would be far more interesting/useful *if* that last question was addressed/answered (and included in the post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you switch orientations, the current activity is destroyed and created again for layout purposes. You can prevent this a few different ways, but throw     android:configChanges="orientation"
In your activity section of your Manifest file. It should prevent the orientation from restarting the activity

Comment: Thats the first time i heard about that. Is there a downside to this? Handling screen orientation changes wss always this cumbersome and now you tell me I dont even have to do it?

Comment: You CAN handle the orientation changes yourself but it can be annoying if you have a lot on screen at the time. But changing orientations, by default, does recreate the activity. Stupid way to do it in my opinion.

Comment: but i want to recreat activity and also want that my song not reset any other solution please help me

Answer (score 4):

Another way if you don't want to handle the orientation yourself. Save the mediaplayer current position in onSaveInstantState();

```
   @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("currPos", music.get(SongPlaying)).getCurrentPosition());
    }
```

then have a variable that holds the current position and in onCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle state){
         if( state != null ){
             playerCurrentPosition = state.getInt("currPos"));
         }
        //Then when you play your media use seekTo(playerCurrentPosition);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this wonderful tip, it really help me alot.

Answer (score 1):

The Activity reloads when you change the orientation.Hence you can lock your orientation to prevent the activity from reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Screen orientation change effectively means your current activity is restarted. Log your onCreate and onDestroy, youll see. 
I find this one of the rare but very unpleasant surprises with android development, youll have to save the current status of your activity and restore them manually.